# How to return mysql Query error from a DAO function in Golang

Tags: mysql, go, error-handling

I want to return a MySQL `Query` error from a DAO function to the caller. But the error creates a `panic` and halt the program. So nothing is returned to the caller. The DAQ function is below

```
var sqlquery="SELECT idfrom table where id=?"

func (mdao DbConn) Daoprocess(tz *entities.Workflowentity) ([]entities.WorkflowResponseEntity, error) {
    log.Println("In side dao")
    values := []entities.WorkflowResponseEntity{}
    rows, err := mdao.DB.Query(sqlquery, tz.Id)
    defer rows.Close()
    if err != nil {
       //code halts here. Nothing returns after here
       return values, err
    }
   for rows.Next() {
       value := entities.WorkflowResponseEntity{}
        err:=rows.Scan(&value.Id)
       if err != nil {
          log.Print("Daoprocess Scan Error", err)
           return values, err
       }
       values = append(values, value)
   }
   return values, nil
}
```

My caller function is like that

```
values, err1 := dataAccess.Daoprocess(tz)
log.Print("\n\n INSIDE MODEL")
log.Print(err1)
if err1 != nil {
    return t, false, err1, "Something Went Wrong"
}
```

The error is :

```
2021/03/17 15:41:14 http: panic serving [::1]:53440: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine 6 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc00010cb40)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1801 +0x147
panic(0x8c7460, 0xc419e0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:975 +0x3e9
database/sql.(*Rows).close(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:3155 +0x76
database/sql.(*Rows).Close(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:3151 +0x33
panic(0x8c7460, 0xc419e0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:969 +0x175
database/sql.(*Rows).Next(0x0, 0xa095e0)
    /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:2835 +0x30
iFIX/ifix/dao.DbConn.Checkprocessdelete(0xc000071d40, 0xc0001167e0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/subham/Documents/Projects/go/iFIX/ifix/dao/workflowdao.go:85 +0x227
iFIX/ifix/models.Checkprocessdelete(0xc0001167e0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/subham/Documents/Projects/go/iFIX/ifix/models/workflowmodel.go:350 +0x288
iFIX/ifix/handlers.Checkprocessdelete(0xa08c20, 0xc00017a0e0, 0xc00017e000)
    /home/subham/Documents/Projects/go/iFIX/ifix/handlers/workflowHandler.go:292 +0x237
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x9868d0, 0xa08c20, 0xc00017a0e0, 0xc00017e000)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2042 +0x44
iFIX/ifix/router.PostMiddleware.func1(0xa08c20, 0xc00017a0e0, 0xc00017e000)
    /home/subham/Documents/Projects/go/iFIX/ifix/router/router.go:45 +0x659
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc000178a00, 0xa08c20, 0xc00017a0e0, 0xc00017e000)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2042 +0x44
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0xc53460, 0xa08c20, 0xc00017a0e0, 0xc00017e000)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2417 +0x1ad
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc00017a000, 0xa08c20, 0xc00017a0e0, 0xc00017e000)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2843 +0xa3
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc00010cb40, 0xa095a0, 0xc000058300)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1925 +0x8ad
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2969 +0x36c
```

I want to handle the error and return it to the caller.But it creates a panic.How to pass it to the caller function?

Comment: Note that the stack-trace shows that the panic is coming from `DbConn.Checkprocessdelete` but your code example shows the method `DbConn.Daoprocess`. It will be difficult for us to help you solve the panic while looking at code that does not cause that panic.

Comment: @mkopriva I renamed the Checkprocessdelete to Daoprocess for better understanding.Forget to delete it from error log. Both the function are same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the defer close func after the nil error check, as example:

```
if err != nil {
   //code halts here. Nothing returns after here
   return values, err
}
defer rows.Close()
```

Comment: I did it before. But the problem was if an error occurred the `rows. close()` function is not called .

Comment: @Subham if an error is returned by `Query` then there's no need to close the `rows` because in that case `rows` is gonna be `nil` which is why you're getting the panic. So there is no need to invoke `rows.Close()` before first establishing that `Query` was successful. Matteo's answer is correct.

Comment: But At first, when I did this after some error occurred, the MySQL service is hanged due to `too many connections. After restarting the MySQL service, everything becomes normal. This happened every time when an error occurred .

Comment: @Subham that only means that you're not releasing connections properly *somewhere* in your app, could be anywhere, it doesn't have to be `Checkprocessdelete`. Still, the fact is, calling `Close` on a `nil` value of `*sql.Rows` will always panic.

Comment: @mkopriva Ok..I 'll check it in my code base.I think you are right.

Comment: @Subham make sure you never use `_, err := db.Query(...` nor `_, := QueryRow(...`, if you don't care about the result of a query then use `_, err := db.Exec(...`. When using `Query` always, after first checking the error, call `rows.Close()`. When using `QueryRow` always call `row.Scan(...`.

Comment: @mkopriva If I use `rows.Close()`  after the error checking, then how the resultset will be closed? Is it automatically closed while an error occurred?

Comment: @Subham that's what `defer` is for. The `defer` statement schedules `rows.Close()` to be invoked just before the enclosing function exits, regardless of whether it exited with an error or not.

Comment: @Subham if you're asking how the connection is released in the case where `Query` returns an error, then *yes*, the connection is released automatically in that case, either by `database/sql` or by the specific driver that you're using. If you're 100% certain that you are closing every db resource that could potentially hold a connection hostage and you're still getting the "too many connections" error then the problem may be in how you configured the db handle, or how your db server is configured, or something else... either way, calling `Close` on `nil` will not prevent such an issue.

Comment: Note that there is no guarantee that `rows` will be `nil` if `err` is not. Generally you want to `defer func(){ if rows != nil { rows.Close() } }` regardless of whether `err == nil`. Same for most resources - if the resource isn't `nil`, it should be safe & necessary to close it, regardless of the error value.